# Grammar Agreements?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Someone I — usually — speak to wrote me, something like this:

> It has, and may never, exist

exist, existed?

What form would one use to get though grammatically proper, in English?

Comment: The quote does not make a meaningful sentence. What do you think the other person wanted to say?

Comment: Can you add more explanation of what each half ("has" vs "may never") of the conjunction is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence attempts to combine

> It has never existed

and

> It may never exist.

When you combine sentences in this way, they should both require the same form of "exist." That is not the case here. Grammatically, combining them is wrong regardless of which form of "exist" you choose.  However, people will often not notice this type of error. So we are left with two alternatives that are both equally wrong in a technical sense:

1. It has, and may never, exist
2. It has, and may never, existed

Between the two, #1 seems less awkward to me.

Comment: Yes! Excellent, farnsy! Wow. Good. Hm . . . So, wait; I thought, I maybe saw people, maybe, connect things, like this. Has this some grammatical issue I could, maybe, read, somewhere?